# Break strings into substrings based on delimiters, with empty substrings

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am using LUA to create a table within a table, and am running into an issue. I need to also populate the NIL values that appear, but can not seem to get it right.

String being manipulated:

```
PatID = '07-26-27~L73F11341687Per^^^SCI^SP~N7N558300000Acc^'

for word in PatID:gmatch("[^\~w]+") do table.insert(PatIDTable,word) end
local _, PatIDCount = string.gsub(PatID,"~","")

PatIDTableB = {}
for i=1, PatIDCount+1 do
   PatIDTableB[i] = {}
end

for j=1, #PatIDTable do
 for word in PatIDTable[j]:gmatch("[^\^]+") do
  table.insert(PatIDTableB[j], word)         
 end
end
```

This currently produces this output:

```
table
[1]=table
 [1]='07-26-27'
[2]=table
 [1]='L73F11341687Per'
 [2]='SCI'
 [3]='SP'
[3]=table
 [1]='N7N558300000Acc'
```

But I need it to produce:

```
table
[1]=table
 [1]='07-26-27'
[2]=table
 [1]='L73F11341687Per'
 [2]=''
 [3]=''
 [4]='SCI'
 [5]='SP'
[3]=table
 [1]='N7N558300000Acc'
 [2]=''
```

EDIT:
I think I may have done a bad job explaining what it is I am looking for. It is not necessarily that I want the karats to be considered "NIL" or "empty", but rather, that they signify that a new string is to be started.

They are, I guess for lack of a better explanation, position identifiers.

So, for example:

```
L73F11341687Per^^^SCI^SP
```

actually translates to:

```
1. L73F11341687Per
2. 
3. 
4. SCI
5. SP
```

If I were to have

```
L73F11341687Per^12ABC^^SCI^SP
```

Then the positions are:

```
1. L73F11341687Per
2. 12ABC
3. 
4. SCI
5. SP
```

And in turn, the table would be:

```
table
[1]=table
 [1]='07-26-27'
[2]=table
 [1]='L73F11341687Per'
 [2]='12ABC'
 [3]=''
 [4]='SCI'
 [5]='SP'
[3]=table
 [1]='N7N558300000Acc'
 [2]=''
```

Hopefully this sheds a little more light on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between `SCI` and `SP` in the answer you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we've cleared up what the question is about, here's the issue.

Your `gmatch` pattern will return all of the matching substrings in the given string. However, your `gmatch` pattern uses "+". That means "one or more", which therefore *cannot* match an empty string. If it encounters a `^` character, it just skips it.

But, if you just tried `:gmatch("[^\^]*")`, which allows empty matches, the problem is that it would effectively turn every `^` character into an empty match. Which is not what you want.

What you want is to eat the `^` at the end of a substring. But, if you try `:gmatch("([^\^])\^")`, you'll find that it won't return the last string. That's because the last string doesn't end with `^`, so it isn't a valid match.

The closest you can get with `gmatch` is this pattern: `"([^\^]*)\^?"`. This has the downside of putting an empty string at the end. However, you can just remove that easily enough, since one will always be placed there.

Comment: I now understand why this is occurring, but I am a little confused as to how I would go about making the necessary correction. I am not sure how I could use an empty string in place of the karats and still have the table populate the necessary values.

Comment: @AllistaireMair: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AllistaireMair: That doesn't change my answer. What you want cannot be done with `gmatch`. It won't return an empty match. So you're going to have to manually process the string.

Comment: Sigh...well thank you very much for looking at this for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: @AllistaireMair: Actually, I may have spoken too soon. Let me check something.

Comment: @AllistaireMair: There, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
local s0 = '07-26-27~L73F11341687Per^^^SCI^SP~N7N558300000Acc^'

local tt = {}
for s1 in (s0..'~'):gmatch'(.-)~' do
    local t = {}
    for s2 in (s1..'^'):gmatch'(.-)^' do
        table.insert(t, s2)
    end
    table.insert(tt, t)
end
```